# Python TK Notebook tab change check

Tags: python, events, tk-toolkit

Newbie programmer here. I am building a tk based desktop app and ran into an issue:

I have a main window with several stuff in it including two tabs:

```
    global nBook
    nBook = ttk.Notebook(self, name="book")
    nBook.place(x=300,y=400)
    frameOne = ttk.Frame(nBook, width=100, height=100)
    frameTwo = ttk.Frame(nBook, width=100, height=100)
    nBook.add(frameOne, text='T1')
    nBook.add(frameTwo, text='T2')
    frameOne.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", self.routine())
    frameTwo.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", self.routine())
```

**routine()** is a function that SHOULD perform a check **every time T2 is selected**

```
def routine(self):
    if str(nBook.index(nBook.select())) == "2":
        # Do stuff
    else:
        pass
```

Problem is that it doesn't do anything when the tab is changed except for calling the routine function as soon as I open the app and never again. I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Could anyone point out the mistake(s) I'm making?

EDIT: Same issue if I try

```
nBook.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", self.xbRoutine())
```

Comment: For me the question was very helpful, but I stumbled over the bind command. For anyone having the same problem, you need to change the bind command to ```nb.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", self.routine)``` instead of ```frameOne/frameTwo```.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error comes from the event binding statements: when using `self.routine()` the callback is called when the `bind` statement is executed, not when the event is triggered. To get the correct behavior, the second argument of `bind` should be the name of a function not a call to this function, so simply remove the parentheses.

Another error: when using `bind`, the callback function is expected to have a first argument (traditionnaly called `event`) storing the event parameters. So you should define your callback as:

```
def routine(self, event):
    ...
```

Comment: Worked wonderfully by defining the callback with (self, event) args and changing the bind arg from self.routine() to self.routine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The answer given by @sciroccorics is not complete.
What you bind is not the tab itself, but the notebook.

So, it should be

```
nBook.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", self.xbRoutine)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use `lambda`.
In your case this will look something like this:

```
frameOne.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", lambda _: self.routine())
```

Don't forget the `_`, otherwise you will get a TypeError, since the event is passed as an argument.

`lamba` is really helpful if your function requires one or more arguments.